# Need help finding a horror movie (horror buffs)

Tags: story-identification, movie

This movie might have been an all Asian staff if not there was a girl with piercings in it that was.(I think)

They are stuck in an elevator (or some room) and they can’t get out. It seems like a witch presents influenced the movie. I believe the piercings that the girl had end up underneath her skin. I also remember a stuck up female character and a make character that seemed like a murder, at first. Don’t remember anyone surviving the end.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: "a witch presents"? I don't know what this means. Are you saying that there was a witch in the film or that the movie was similar to something else?

Comment: Weren't the piercings already in her skin?

Comment: I believe that it was said in the film and the movie was implying it. She had piercing but something happened where she was cursed and she felt needles in her skin.

Comment: @J.S. - In roughly which year or decade did you watch this, and when do you think it might've been made? Also, what language did you watch it in, and was it dubbed or subtitled?

Comment: Um, https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1314655/ Devil maybe?  It is a horror in an elevator.  At the same time though, some of those elements sound like Hellraiser, so I'd need more details.